# Getting the same (X,Y) of a MotionEvent for the same place regardless of screen orientation

Tags: android

On a regular Android screen, the origin is top left and if I tilt it to a landscape orientation, it will be in the "new" top left position.

I'm in need of getting the (X, Y) position of a touch event but always considering the origin is in the same place (The (0,0) should stay in one corner, regardless of screen orientation).

I'm not sure if this is a math problem or if this is an Android problem. I'm currently using getX(int i) as I need to support multiple fingers but as I said, if the user tilts the phone, the origin will switch place and I will get (in this case) wrong (X,Y).

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to track the orientation.  Then detect the orientation change and change your variable.

In my activity I'd declare a variable:

```
int mOrientation;
```

In `onCreate()` set the current orientation:

```
mOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration();
```

Then I'd override `onConfigurationChanged()`

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mOrientation = newConfig.orientation;
}
```

Then in your `onTouchListener` check `mOrientation` to see if you need to swap x or y to make sure your coordinates stay the same.  If you want to assume coordinates are always based on portrait, then if the orientation is landscape getX() becomes the y value and getY() becomes the x value.

Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE and Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT are the int values you can check against.  See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) for more info on the constant values.

Comment: This is closer but it's not quite right. I've illustrated it in a picture here: http://i.imgur.com/MTznQX4.jpg?1

I want to get (10, 700) in all cases. Without any fix I get (700, 300) in the top one and something like (40, 10) in the right one. Just switching them will only work on one parameter. 

However, if I do something like `x = width - getX()` in the right one and `y = height - getY()` in the top one I would get the right answer? But then I would have to know the difference between the two landscape orientations

Comment: Got it.  Not sure how you can account for reverse landscape orientation... if I think of something I'll add a comment.

Comment: I used getRotation() to find the rotation of the device and changed x and y based on that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2296440 Great, glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the getRotation() method which gave me the rotation in degrees. After that I changed the coordinates based on that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to get the screen coordinates. Check below code

```
Display mdisp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point mdispSize = new Point();
    mdisp.getSize(mdispSize);
    int maxX = mdispSize.x; 
    int maxY = mdispSize.y;
```

Comment: Actually no, I want to get the same (X,Y) position of a MotionEvent regardless of screen orientation. event.getX() will give you different values if your screen is portrait/landscape for the same spot on the screen